# Will RandomAccessFile use a lot of memory when openning large-size file?

Tags: java

I am wondering if RandomAccessFile uses a lot of memory when openning a large-size file or not?

Comment: Opening a file doesn't use *any* memory. (Ok, it uses a tiny bit for the file descriptor and what not ..).

Comment: Memory mapping the file doesn't use much heap either.

Answer (score 3):

No.  It just allows you to read and write to specific locations within the file, it doesn't maintain any data internally about the file.